# Parameterize Query while using OFFSET clause

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've used following stored procedure and try to parameterize the query by passing the number parameter. However it gives me error while executing the stored procedure. Any insights is really helpful

```
function uspGetUsersByPage(number) {
  //Set Environment
  let context = getContext();
  let coll = context.getCollection();
  let link = coll.getSelfLink();
  let response = context.getResponse(); 

  let query = {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.DocumentType = "UserRole" and a.AuditFields.IsLatest = true and a.AuditFields.IsDeleted = false OFFSET @number LIMIT 20'
    , parameters: [{ name: '@number', value: number }]
  };


  //Execute the query against the collection
  let runquery = coll.queryDocuments(link, query, {}, callbackfn);

  //Call function to throw an error(if any) or display the output
  function callbackfn(err, queryoutput) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    if (!queryoutput || !queryoutput.length) {
      response.setBody(null);
    }
    else {
      response.setBody(queryoutput);
    }
  };

  //Display standard output if query doesnt get any results
  if (!runquery) { throw Error('Unable to retrieve requested information'); }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my simple test following your description.

Data:

[image]

Stored procedure:

```
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var query =  {query: "SELECT c.id,c.number FROM c offset @num limit 1", parameters: 
[{name: "@num", value: prefix}]};

   console.log(query);
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        query,
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();   
            response.setBody(feed);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jay for the guidance. The solution is either to send the input as custom or use parseInt in the store procedure. Its resolved now.